# "You are in emergency mode" after "shutdown -r now"

Tags: mount, dependencies

Yesterday I was trying some Linux commands in my system. After running "shutdown -r now", my system just rebooted and showing errors. The errors are,

```
Dependency failed for /home
Dependency failed for /opt
Dependency failed for local file systems
```

I tried my best to troubleshoot trying others post. But still, I couldn't resolve it. Result from `journalctl -xb`:

[image]

Comment: Is our system back up today?  My best guess would be that the shutdown command had shutdown the disks, and they had not powered back up in a timely manner.

Comment: @SumiSubu uhm maybe don't run experimental commands like that? if you want to reboot it's `sudo reboot`

Comment: @tatsu Experimental?

Comment: as in: he doesn't know what they are going to do but runs them anyways and then regrets are had. ...he is experimenting. the same way I was when I was figuring out how windows ME worked by deleting one file after the other in system32

Comment: @tatsu +1 for experimenting with a system in order to determine what's what, although getting it running again may be difficult!

Comment: I had not viewed you screen image before, but it is clear that one (or more) disks are not prepared to operate.  If your computer is not operational today, I would suggest booting a live USB to see if the disk is failed and possibly to backup data prior to attempting further operations.

Comment: @tatsu `sudo reboot now` is equivalent to `sudo shutdown -r now`.....

Comment: fair enough. I didn't know. but then if it's the same it can't be the cause of his issue.